# Read in a tab delimited file with observations on multiple rows

Tags: r, import, csv

ANSWERED: specifying a quote option in the scan function solved the problem

I have a data set in a tab delimited text file that contains names, addresses, and property info. I have tried

```
land <- as.data.frame(scan(paste0(dirdata, "land.txt" ),what=list(CFullName="", CAddr1= "", CAddr2="", Amount="",CDate= "", Financer= "", Filing="", Sched= "", Office="", Dist= "", County= "", Municipality= ""), sep = "\t" , flush = TRUE, multi.line=TRUE, skip= 20, na.strings = "NA"))
```

In the data below, there should only be three lines per observation. The first is the name, second is the street address, the third begins with the city and contains the remainder of the variables.

```
MORRIS, WILLIAM
1111 POLARIS PKWY OH1-1213
COLUMBUS, OH 43240  12.00   15-MAY-12   J. P. MORGAN CHASE & CO.    2012 July   A   N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
JACOBS, WILLIAM
3477 COURTLAND DRIVE
LEWIS CENTER, OH 43035  12.00   30-SEP-09   J. P. MORGAN CHASE & CO.    2009 11     A   N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
MARTIN, WILLIAM
3477 COURTLAND DRIVE
LEWIS CENTER, OH 43035  12.00   31-DEC-09   J. P. MORGAN CHASE & CO.    2010 January A  N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
MICHAELS, WILLIAM
1111 POLARIS PKWY OH1-1213
COLUMBUS, OH 43240  12.00   15-AUG-12   J. P. MORGAN CHASE & CO.    2012    A   N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
BROWN, WILLIAM
1111 POLARIS PKWY OH1-0213
COLUMBUS, OH 43240  12.00   31-JUL-13   J. P. MORGAN CHASE & CO. PAC    2013 32 A   N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
BAXTER, WILLIAM
3477 COURTLAND DRIVE
LEWIS CENTER, OH 43035  12.00   15-AUG-09   J. P. MORGAN CHASE & CO. PAC    2009 11     A   N/A     N/A     N/A     N/A
```

My code reads in the first 2,517 observations correctly but then stops when there should be at least 12,000 observations based on the txt file. The error my code gives is:

```
EOF within quoted stringnumber of items read is not a multiple of the number of columnsRead 2517 records
```

Thank you!

Comment: your file may actually be tab-delimited, but it doesn't copy for me, so I cannot test this, but you could `readLines` your file, `split` every 3 lines and collapse those 3 by `\t`, collapse all those lines by `\n`, and then `read.table` but like I said, I tried this and your tab characters are lost in the copy/paste it seems

Comment: for example, `l <- readLines('text.txt'); s <- split(l, rep(1:(length(l) / 3), each = 3)); p <- paste(sapply(s, paste, collapse = '\t'), collapse = '\n'); read.table(text = p, sep = '\t')`

Comment: I would open that file with an editor (like notepad++ if you are on windows)  that allows you to see the invisible characters and examine line 2517 and around it - it looks like there might be some missing data there.